# Macros in LaTeX class

Tags: macros, enumerate

I have the following macros in a LaTeX class:

```
\def\labelenumi{\theenumi.}
\def\theenumi{\arabic{enumi}}

\def\labelenumii{(\theenumii)}
\def\theenumii{\alph{enumii}}
\def\p@enumii{\theenumi}

\def\labelenumiii{\theenumiii.}
\def\theenumiii{\roman{enumiii}}
\def\p@enumiii{\theenumi(\theenumii)}

\def\labelenumiv{\theenumiv.}
\def\theenumiv{\Alph{enumiv}}
\def\p@enumiv{\p@enumiii\theenumiii}
```

I understand that these are for numbering but I don't quite understand them. Can someone please explain what these do and how to use them?
I have a related question. 
Now I'm little confused. I find another set of macro's defined in my latex class following the above macro's. Here's an illustration:

```
\def\labelitemi{\m@th\bullet}
\def\labelitemii{\bfseries --}  
\def\labelitemiii{\m@th\ast}    
\def\labelitemiv{\m@th\cdot}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item 
 level 1
 \begin{enumerate}
\item 
level 2
 \begin{enumerate}
\item 
level 3
 \begin{enumerate}
\item 
level 4
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

These seem do the same job that was done by the macro's I mentioned earlier. But this is simpler! Since both are included I wonder there is a subtle difference which I'm overlooking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't use them directly; they're used internally by the `enumerate` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These define the labeling for enumeration lists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\labelenumi{\theenumi.}
\def\theenumi{\arabic{enumi}}

\def\labelenumii{(\theenumii)}
\def\theenumii{\alph{enumii}}
\def\p@enumii{\theenumi}

\def\labelenumiii{\theenumiii.}
\def\theenumiii{\roman{enumiii}}
\def\p@enumiii{\theenumi(\theenumii)}

\def\labelenumiv{\theenumiv.}
\def\theenumiv{\Alph{enumiv}}
\def\p@enumiv{\p@enumiii\theenumiii}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item level 1
\begin{enumerate}
\item level 2
\begin{enumerate}
\item level 3
\begin{enumerate}
\item level 4
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

latex `enumerate` uses different counters depending on nesting level. A top level enumerate uses `enumi` an enumerate inside an item of that uses `enumii` etc.

These set up the print style used by the counter. Taking the second level

```
\def\labelenumii{(\theenumii)}
\def\theenumii{\alph{enumii}}
\def\p@enumii{\theenumi}
```

`\theenumi` is the usual `the`... associated with every latex counter, and gives its default print form. Here `\alph` so a,b,c,...

`\labelenumi` is the form used in the enumerate lable here `(a)`, `(b)` etc,te the brackets are just in the label not in `\theenumii` so not in cross references or other uses of the counter.

`\p@enumi` is the prefix used in cross references. so here it is `\theenumi` that is the print form of the surrounding item, so the if this enumerate is in item 2 of an outer list and this is item 2 of this list `\p@enumi` will be `2` and a `\ref` will produce `2b` for this item which is labelled `(b)`.